# How do you convert command line args in python to a dictionary?

Tags: python, command-line, argv, sys

I'm writing an application that takes arbitrary command line arguments, and then passes them onto a python function:

```
$ myscript.py --arg1=1 --arg2=foobar --arg1=4
```

and then inside myscript.py:

```
import sys
argsdict = some_function(sys.argv)
```

where `argsdict` looks like this:

```
{'arg1': ['1', '4'], 'arg2': 'foobar'}
```

I'm sure there is a library somewhere that does this, but I can't find anything.

**EDIT:** argparse/getopt/optparse is not what I'm looking for. These libraries are for defining an interface that is the same for each invocation. I need to be able to handle arbitrary arguments.

Unless, argparse/optparse/getopt has functionality that does this...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: argparse is completely different, its for defining a commandline interface. I'm trying to parse an arbitrary commandline interface. Each invocation of this script will have different arguments each time.

Comment: I *think* it's still possible to do that with argparse.  If you don't want to use it, then AFAIK you have no option but to write a parser for the arguments yourself.

Comment: Yes I also can't figure out how to parse arbitrary arguments with the standard libraries...

Comment: Is this still unsolved 5 years later? Do I need to write this thing??

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

**myscript.py**

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
for k, v in ((k.lstrip('-'), v) for k,v in (a.split('=') for a in sys.argv[1:])):
    d[k].append(v)

print dict(d)
```

**Result:**

```
C:\>python myscript.py  --arg1=1 --arg2=foobar --arg1=4
{'arg1': ['1', '4'], 'arg2': ['foobar']}
```

Note: the value will always be a list, but I think this is more consistent. If you really want the final dictionary to be

```
{'arg1': ['1', '4'], 'arg2': 'foobar'}
```

then you could just run

```
for k in (k for k in d if len(d[k])==1):
    d[k] = d[k][0]
```

afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using `argparse`, although it's a stretch. I wouldn't call this complete solution, but rather a good start.

```
class StoreInDict(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        d = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        for opt in values:
            k,v = opt.split("=", 1)
            k = k.lstrip("-")
            if k in d:
                d[k].append(v)
            else:
                d[k] = [v]
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, d)

# Prevent argparse from trying to distinguish between positional arguments
# and optional arguments. Yes, it's a hack.
p = argparse.ArgumentParser( prefix_chars=' ' )

# Put all arguments in a single list, and process them with the custom action above,
# which convertes each "--key=value" argument to a "(key,value)" tuple and then
# merges it into the given dictionary.
p.add_argument("options", nargs="*", action=StoreInDict, default=dict())

args = p.parse_args("--arg1=1 --arg2=foo --arg1=4".split())
print args.options
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import sys

argsdict = {}

for farg in sys.argv:
    if farg.startswith('--'):
        (arg,val) = farg.split("=")
        arg = arg[2:]

        if arg in argsdict:
            argsdict[arg].append(val)
        else:
            argsdict[arg] = [val]
```

Slightly different from specified, the value is always a list.

Comment: I recommend using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) for your variable `argsdict`. This way you get rid of the `in` test and can append without worrying. It makes your code more concise and expressive and therefore pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used today, it accounts for:

`--key=val`, `--key`, `-key`, `-key val`

```
def clean_arguments(args):
    ret_args = defaultdict(list)

    for index, k in enumerate(args):
        if index < len(args) - 1:
            a, b = k, args[index+1]
        else:
            a, b = k, None

        new_key = None

        # double hyphen, equals
        if a.startswith('--') and '=' in a:
            new_key, val = a.split('=')

        # double hyphen, no equals
        # single hyphen, no arg
        elif (a.startswith('--') and '=' not in a) or \
                (a.startswith('-') and (not b or b.startswith('-'))):
            val = True

        # single hypen, arg
        elif a.startswith('-') and b and not b.startswith('-'):
            val = b

        else:
            if (b is None) or (a == val):
                continue

            else:
                raise ValueError('Unexpected argument pair: %s, %s' % (a, b))

        # santize the key
        key = (new_key or a).strip(' -')
        ret_args[key].append(val)

    return ret_args
```

Answer (score 0):

..may I ask **why** are you trying to rewrite (a bunch of) wheels, when you have:

- http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html
- ...etc, etc, etc...

?

EDIT:

In reply to your edit, optparse/argparse (the later one only available in >=2.7) are flexible enough to extend to suit your needs, while maintaining a consistent interface (eg. a user expects to be able to use both `--arg=value` and `--arg value`, `-a value` and `-avalue`, etc.. using a pre-existent library, you don't have to worry about supporting all those syntaxes, etc.).

Comment: how would you extend argparse, for instance, to parse arbitrary arguments? can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

> Or something like this) Sorry, if this is stupid, I am a newbie:)
>
> $ python3 Test.py a 1 b 2 c 3

```
import sys

def somefunc():
    keys = []
    values = []
    input_d = sys.argv[1:]

    for i in range(0, len(input_d)-1, 2):
        keys.append(input_d[i])
        values.append(input_d[i+1])

    d_sys = dict(zip(keys, values))

somefunc()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to write something of your own instead of a proper command-line parsing library, for your input this should work:

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.lstrip('-').split('='),sys.argv[1:]))
```

You'll want to add something to catch arguments without an '=' in them.

Comment: This will not give the desired results. Using the OPs example, `arg1` would not map to `1` and `4`, but only to `4`.