# How to read variable length command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I want to give command line inputs to my script.
which has input arguments as :

1. my script.py
2. mode name (which is id)
3. id numbers ( passed by ',' separations
   first command, in which I would pass multiple ids through command line
   `myscript.py id id1,id2,id3...`

second command, where I would a '-f' flag at the end which denotes force and it must do that operation.

`myscript.py id 123,21,1,900 -f`

My question is, how should I read in and use these arguments in the script?
Thank you !

Comment: Use `argparse`. It has built-in options to do this.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can get argument from `sys` library.
Basic implementation

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv)
if "-f" in sys.argv:
    print("force")
print(sys.argv[1], "=", sys.argv[2])
```

```
python file.py id id1,id2,id3 -f

> ['.\\file.py', 'id', 'id1,id2,id3', '-f']
> force
> id = id1,id2,id3
```

If you want as dictionary format you can view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807809)